# Copy data between Data Grids VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, forms, datagrid, parent-child

Today i'm trying to pass a variable between two datagrids.
The first is on an main form, and the second is in a dialog form.

I tried using functions and also through public variables like this:
Invoice_new (Parent FORM):

Controls:

```
DatagridView: invoice_items

Public WriteOnly Property ValueFromChild() As String
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        MsgBox(Value) 'Work
        With Me.invoice_items
            .Rows.Add() 'Does not WORK
            .Item(0, 0).Value() = Value 'Does not WORK
        End With
    End Set
End Property
```

invoice_new_search_item (Child FORM)

Controls:

```
DatagridView: search_items

invoice_new.ValueFromChild() = search_items.Item(0, current_row).Value
```

I tried many ways to do this but I can not any solution, someone give me some idea to do this would be really grateful.

Comment: Could you give some details and code on what you have attempted, and how those attempts failed?

Comment: I modified the answer, explaining more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use delegates to pass information between a main form and dialog form. For instance your variable to be used in both datagrids. I'd give this a quick google.

[A Beginner's Guide to Delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13607/A-Beginner-s-Guide-to-Delegates)

Hope this is helpful and what you are looking for.